# objective c group phone calls by type and number

Tags: objective-c

I have calls history from server, how can I group items by phone number and call type like as iPhone phone application? I did it like this, number grouped but I need group by phone call type.

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *groups = [allEntities valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.fromNumber"];
for (NSString *groupId in groups) {
    NSMutableDictionary *entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];
     [entry setObject:groupId forKey:@"fromNumber"];

    NSArray *groupNames = [allEntities filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fromNumber = %@", groupId]];
    for (int i = 0; i < groupNames.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *name = [[groupNames objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"toNumber"];
        [entry setObject:name forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"toNumber%d", i + 1]];
    }
    [resultArray addObject:entry];
}
NSLog(@"resultArray %@", resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The tel URL scheme is used to launch the Phone app on iOS devices and initiate dialing of the specified phone number. When a user taps a telephone link in a webpage, iOS displays an alert asking if the user really wants to dial the phone number and initiates dialing if the user accepts. When a user opens a URL with the tel scheme in a native app, iOS does not display an alert and initiates dialing without further prompting the user. However, a native app can be configured to display its own alert.

FaceTime in macOS 10.10 and later can also use the tel URL scheme to launch the Phone app on an iOS device by using Handoff. This scenario works when FaceTime is configured to dial phone numbers (the default configuration) and the iOS device is connected to the same iCloud account as the Mac.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12125551212"]];
```

Comment: I don't need to call phone number, I need create grouped call history